# Get myisam_sort_buffer_size value via php?

Tags: php, mysql

SO!

Sorry, maybe stupid question, but...If I have only ftp-credentials - is it possible to get via `php` values like `myisam_sort_buffer_size`, `read_rnd_buffer_size`,etc. from `mysql` settings? I never encountered with this issue. Haven't access to production DB( DB settings - can`t check it) for the moment, but feeling something is working wrong locally.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can query for any configuration variable this way:

```
$value = $pdo->query("SELECT @@myisam_sort_buffer_size")->fetchColumn();
print_r($value);
```

But you shouldn't care about this value, because [you should not use MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706717/20860).

Comment: Great! Thanks, man! P.S. "...because you should not use MyISAM" Yes, I agree with you.